# jQuery event not working on radio button?

Tags: html, jquery

I am having an issue where the jQuery event listener i am attaching to a radio button is not working.

I want to be able to grab the value of individua radio buttons on **CHANGE**. Unfortunately, everything I've tried isn't working. I've looked up some answers here...none worked as well.

BELOW IS MY jQuery code

```
$('input[type=radio][name=method]').click(function() {

    let selectedMethod = $('input[type=radio][name=method]:checked').val();

    console.log(selectedMethod);
});
```

I also tried this

```
$('input[type=radio][name=method]').change(function() {

    let selectedMethod = $('input[type=radio][name=method]:checked').val();

    console.log(selectedMethod);
});
```

I also tried this from an answer here

```
$('input#method').on('ifChecked', function() {

    let selectedMethod = $(this).val();

    console.log(selectedMethod);
});
```

Below is the HTML Radio buttons. The radio buttons are custom-styled to be like CARDS

```
    <label>
         <input type="radio" name="method" id="method" value="pp"
                class="card-input-element" required />
          <div class="card card-default card-input">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
             <img src="img/paypal.png" width="50" /> <br><b>Paypal</b>
           </div>
         </div>
   </label>
```

None is working. I don't know what I am not doing right.

Comment: How does the html look like?

Comment: The radio buttons are customized to clickable cards...

Comment: @NathanaelDousa I've edited the question and added the HTML code for the radio button

Comment: I have tried the second solution you tried (with the ```.change```). This grabs the value completely fine. It console logs the "pp". Are you trying to grab the ```value="pp"``` or ```<b>Paypal</b>```

Comment: @NathanaelDousa the  `value="pp"`

Comment: It's working now. The problem was that the code block for the change event was inside the `$(document).ready(fucntion(){)`

Comment: @NathanaelDousa ... So I took it out of the block and put it just after the end of the `$(document).ready(function (){})` block. And it's working now

Comment: Awesome! Good the hear!

Comment: @NathanaelDousa Thanks, Man... Hmm I don't know but if it's possible there's a way we can communicate outside StackOverflow maybe Twitter or Instagram. I'd like to connect with you... If you don't mind.

Comment: yea sure :) insta: yung_n.d

Answer (score 0):

The second method you tried works completely fine.

Just make sure the selector selects the correct id.
This is what I did.
HTML:

```
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="method" id="method" value="pp" class="card-input-element" required />

        <div class="card card-default card-input">
        <div class="card-body text-center">
            <img src="img/paypal.png" width="50" /> <br><b>Paypal</b>
        </div>
        </div>
    </label>
```

Jquery:

```
//test id make sure the selector is correct..
$('#method').change(function() {

 let selectedMethod = $('input[type=radio][name=method]:checked').val();
 //this console logs "pp"
 console.log(selectedMethod);
});
```